# Wait for systemd oneshot service before shutdown

Tags: systemd, services

I'm trying to setup automatic execution of a process using a systemd timer and service. The problem is that my oneshot service gets immediately killed on shutdown. How can I tell systemd to not kill oneshot services but wait for it to finish before shutdown?

My test.service looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=My automatic updates
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sleep 40
TimeoutSec=0
```

Comment: Can't you use just `Type=simple`?

Comment: @paladin Can you explain how this change alters how systemd handles the running unit at shutdown? (I'm here with the exact same question as OP.)

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.service.html search for "oneshot", in short, if you use default settings, systemd will regard a oneshot service as dead after it had been started. Meaning, if you shutdown your system, a wrongly configured oneshot service (which actually is not dead, but regarded as dead by systemd) will look like a malfunctioning service for systemd and thus being killed. You could also use `RemainAfterExit=` option to counteract this.

Comment: PS also take a look at `ExecStop=`

Comment: But a oneshot service is not "started" until the ExecStart has exited. The context here is shutdown happening while it is still executing, so "activating (starting)" in systemd's eyes. I've not seen any documentation stating how shutdown addresses services in this state.

Comment: What OP I think is asking is: does systemd have any built-in way to tell it: "Do not under any circumstances stop this unit (or kill it during shutdown) until ExecStart has exited". And as far as I can tell, the answer is "No."

Comment: @Headbank yes, this was what I was looking for and I came to the same result like you. But I can live with the workaround described in the question: ignoring the TERM signal in my script. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: The parts you'd already figured out solved the problem for me, so really my thanks to you! One other titbit, if the script is calling subprocesses (like an `rsync` run in my case) then it's an idea to add `KillMode=process` so the TERM will not kill them.

Comment: Reading the manpage for `KillMode=process` brought me to `KillSignal=`. Setting this to something non-destructive like `SIGCONT` also solves the problem without the need to manually ignore signals in my script. Thanks!

Comment: @Headbank _>> But a oneshot service is not "started" until the ExecStart has exited. <<_, that's right, but a oneshot service is not meant to run for a long period of time, it's meant to being shot. This unit type is good for programs which usually only do a little bit stuff and then exit very fast. If you use this type of unit for programs that run more than a few seconds or even longer than the default timeout, you are using the wrong unit type for your program.

Comment: @paladin thanks, I think I was too focused on what happens during "starting" state, but as I've learned that's immaterial here (in either case, normally the process gets a TERM and that's that). My case is a script that normally runs ~10s but sometimes >3m or even can timeout. Because it's a discrete action (repeated using timer) `oneshot` seemed most appropriate but I will switch to `simple` on your advice plus handy FAQ at https://trstringer.com/simple-vs-oneshot-systemd-service/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found 2 possible solutions.

1. Tell your script to ignore the TERM signal and set `TimeoutStopSec=infinity` to avoid systemd SIGKILL your process after it is not responding to SIGTERM. Ignoring the TERM signal can be done e.g. by using `trap` in bash or something in Python like:

   ```
   import signal
   def signal_handler(signum, frame):
     pass
   signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)
   ```

   You should implement a logic to exit your script as soon as possible when receiving the TERM signal.
2. If you can't modify the executable, set `KillSignal=` to something non-destructive like `SIGCONT` (I consider this as a hack and not recommend this).

Comment: On a general pragmatic note I would advise using a suitably high value for `TimeoutStopSec` (as much head-room to allow for worst-case) instead of `infinity` because making it potentially impossible to *ever* shutdown seems unadvisable (or do you trust your service enough to be sure this will never arise?).